# background property issue

Tags: html, css

My background output is not coming as it should be.

I was expecting this
[image: expected output]

only the code that I used is html with external css with empty body tag
`<body></body>` 
css code is:

`body{ background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, blue); }`

but the output came like this.
[image: actual output after pushed code]

Comment: This works perfectly with chrome.

Comment: ok doesn't it works on brave?

Comment: I would guess you have a `body` with no content (and therefor no height), have you tried setting a `height` (or `min-height`) on that element?

Comment: no ,<body> is all empty 
and is there is no other way without using any specific height and with empty content

Comment: Have you seen the answer I posted? I'm not sure my comment is communicating the explanation very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your body has no content, it will have no height and the gradient will be shown as a small line (based on the default padding/margin on the body element) and repeated by default. You can see what's being repeated by disabling the repeat like this:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

To work around this, add a `min-height` to the body:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, blue);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i am unable to detect any problem accept for the fact that you have written `<body></boyd>` instead of `<body></body>`

Comment: sorry my mistake but the code is correct I have made mistake while posting but the code is in correct format.